# Null values while converting string to datetime with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have recently started working with pyspark on databricks and it's funny how I have been getting NULL values when converting the following string to DateTime data type. I have checked several articles here on how to do that but none of them seem worked for me.

sample data

```
    invoiceId  quantity invoicedate
     001         34     12/1/2010 8:26
     003         10     12/2/2010 8:26
     004         10     30/2/2010 8:26
```

I am trying to convert invoicedate (string datatype) into DateTime datatype using pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with example for spark 3.0**

---

This solution is for spark 2, because it's using [Java SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for datetime pattern for
[to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select(
    f.to_timestamp(f.col('invoicedate'), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm').alias('some date')
)
```

In spark 3, [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) uses own [dateformat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) and it's more strict than in spark 2, so if your date doesn't match with datetime pattern you will get the error(like in your case).

So you have 2 options with spark 3:

1. Set property "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy"="LEGACY" and use code from my example above.
2. Specify pattern accroding to [spark3 dateformat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html). Like this:

```py
df.select(
    f.to_timestamp(f.col('invoicedate'), 'd/M/y H:m').alias('some date')
)
```

Anyway you will get null for **30/2/2010 8:26** as there isn't 30 days in Febrary.

Comment: I got this error 
SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '12/1/2010 8:26' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '12/1/2010 8:26' could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: @lee I've updated my answer with example for spark 3

Answer (score 0):

I added the below codes to the codes @Artem Astashov provided and it worked

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY") # this bit 
resolves the issues

df.select(
f.to_timestamp(f.col('invoicedate'), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm').alias('some date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar issue and discovered that i was trying to use string formats that were not for unix timestamps.  I have a string of date that looks like:

```
Fri Nov 16 23:38:16 +0000 2018
```

I could not figure out why i wasn't able to get the to_date or date_format functions to work from `pyspark.sql.functions`.  I finally figured out that the way to do this was using the `unix_time` functions. So i was trying to provide a string format that looked like:

```
"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"
```

But i needed to use the unix_timestamp format which is:

```
"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

Using the correct timestamp formatting then worked using the following code for my dataframe, `"df"`, with a column, `"created_at"`, which the date string format is that as above.

df.select(F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('created_at', 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy'))

I finally found this after digging around for a bit on this helpful stackoverflow article here:
[How to parse twitter date time string in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970882/how-to-parse-twitter-date-time-string-in-pyspark)